# Chrome developer toolbox saving console logs after postback

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome's developer tools to debug/test my application. I notice that after each post back, the logs in the console window seem to clear. Is there anyway to persist them across post backs? For example if I have something like

```
<input type="submit" onClick="RunMyCode();" />
```

and the last line of the "RunMyCode()" javascript is something like

```
console.log("Finished processing. About to submit");
```

This line is getting lost. i.e, the submit seems to finish, a new page loads and the log message from the last page is lost.

Is there anyway to keep/display a running list of these logs in the developer tool's console window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click the console window there's an option to check: `preserve log upon navigation`.

Comment: Thank you for saving my sanity!  (Stupid NULL is not defined was impossible to view because crashing my code CAUSED the postback to go through, since return false never got called)